# How to duplicate a JavaScript array within itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I've got an array:

```
[1,2,3]
```

And I want an array:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Is there a way to do that without looping through the array and pushing each element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3]
console.log(array1.concat(array1))
```

Comment: Perfect. Just didn't know what to call it in my searches. Thanks!

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)

Comment: @adiga thanks I didn't know how to do it without jsfiddle or something like that :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
let array = [1,2,3];
array.push(...array);
console.log(array)
```

Comment: @MaheerAli i kinda make a use of both, `array.push` function gathers any number of arguments with rest parameters, however i get a list of arguments from an array with spread operator

Comment: @MaheerAli this is spread syntax. `rest` is when one *collects* multiple elements while destrucutring and in function arguments

Comment: @adiga thanks for info. I misunderstood a little bit

Answer (score 3):

If you want to duplicate the array `n` times, you could use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) like this:

```js
let duplicate = (arr, n) => Array.from({length: n}).flatMap(a => arr)

console.log(duplicate([1,2,3], 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's with ES6 way of using concat:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3]
array1 = [...array1, ...array1]
console.log(array1)
```

And here's for number of length you desire for:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let ln = array1.length;
let times = ln * 2;
array1 = Array.from({length:times}, (e, i)=>array1[i%ln])
console.log(array1)
```

This will allow you to stop at certain length if you wish. For eg.:

```js
// result: [1,2,3,1,2]
let array1 = [1,2,3];
let ln = array1.length;
let times = ln * 2 - 1;
array1 = Array.from({length:times}, (e, i)=>array1[i%ln])
console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variant with reduce

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce( (acc, item, index, arr) => { acc[index] = acc[index+arr.length] = item; return acc}, [] )
```